# Parallax Code Not Working

Tags: html, css, scroll, parallax, codepen

Copied some code from W3 Schools [found here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) but copying and pasting this directly into my CodePen isn't working. I have googled but I'm not sure if this is a CodePen issue or, more likely, an issue with something I have done wrong.

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
}

.parallax { 
/* The image used */
background-image: url("img_parallax.jpg");

/* Full height */
height: 100%; 

/* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

This is [my CodePen](https://codepen.io/bomaran/pen/prOzxG?editors=1100)

Comment: i think the background image url is not correct

Comment: Ah yes this makes sense. But why does the W3 demo page work then? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_parallax

I changed to another background and viewing the CodePen link you can see that it works. If I want to create more "screens" as the user scrolls down, do you just create more divs?

Comment: because the img is already on their server, but to use it on the codepen, you must upload it to some whereelse or call the full link of the img in w3school like [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax.jpg](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax.jpg)

Comment: Thanks Henry, to create sections or multiple "screens" as the user scrolls down though, do you just repeat the code or create more divs?

Comment: @pistach_io what do you mean? multiple img background scroll like [this](https://1stwebdesigner.com/demos/parallax/) or [this](https://demo.tutorialzine.com/2015/09/6-practical-examples-for-building-parallax-websites/)?

Comment: Yeah exactly thats what I am looking to do.

Comment: Then you can follow their link to the main article and try to recreate them as you wish, though if you don't want fancy animation like the first link, i suggest you use the second link, it just css and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks Henry. Last question, is the first link (in case I want to do fancy animation) doesnt seem to have a link to how they made this parallax site or a tutorial or some sort. Clicking the top left "back to article" looks like a blank link

Comment: Oops, sorry i wrong about the links. The first one [here](https://1stwebdesigner.com/parallax-scrolling-tutorial/) is the one only use css and easy to use. And the second one [here](https://tutorialzine.com/2015/09/6-practical-examples-for-building-parallax-websites) is the fancy one. So sorry!